# Print controller will not appear once called

Tags: ios, pdf, printing

When I call the UIPrintInteractionController it will not appear. I'm not sure what is happening. I have stepped through my code and the line calling the print controller to appear is executed with no problems but it doesn't appear in my simulator. I am printing a pdf file. I don't think that would have anything to do with it. I've looked up some tutorials and Apple's documentation and I am calling the function the same way. Any suggestions would be most helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
NSData *pdfData = [self generatePDFDataForPrinting];
printController.printingItem = pdfData;
[printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your "`printController`" is "`nil`".

To prove this, you can set a breakpoint there and look at it, or you can change that second line to this:

```
if(printController)
{
    printController.printingItem = pdfData;
} else {
    NSLog( @"Michael is right, printController hasn't been instantiated yet" );
}
```

How did you set up your "`printController`"?  Also, do you check to see if you get a "`YES`" back from a call to "`[UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable]`"?

Comment: You are right I forgot to setup the print controller. Thanks for the quick response.